# PHPMailer send mail like text, but isHTML = true

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('info@example.pro', 'KitApp');
$mail->addAddress('info@example.pro');
$mail->addAddress('topsuak@example.com');
$mail->addAddress('lexxsumy@example.com');
$mail->addAddress('sales@example.pro');
$mail->Subject = 'example - оценка проекта';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = '<div>
    <h2>Клиент выполнил оценку проекта.</h2>
    <p>Имя: <b>'. 'sdfsdf' .'</b></p>
    <p>Контакты: <b>'.'sadsad'.'</b></p>
</div>';
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
```

this code sending message with HTTP headers like text:

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--b1_kMw0lvaLD8a9kzvOpaPvFScTz5hnroHb3FHDBNGivk

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

```
<div>
<h2>Клиент выполнил оценку проекта.</h2>
<p>Имя: <b>бек1</b></p>
<p>Контакты: <b>тест</b></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can see that it *is* setting a content-type correctly for HTML, and it's normal for messages to have headers that look like HTTP, because HTTP uses MIME for that, and MIME was defined for email first. Are you using latest PHPMailer?

Comment: How are you verifying message rendering? Does your email client support HTML? Also, have you redacted output? It looks unusual to type `<div>` and get `<\div>`.

Comment: I tried to run this script on another hosting and everything worked, maybe you know some php.ini settings that could affect this?

Comment: I added a backslash because stackoverflow treated it as markup

Comment: Then please use the `{}` (Code Sample) toolbar button. You already did it with PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what version of php?

if php8 try to edit PHPMailer.php like this

```
const CRLF = "\n";
protected static $LE = "\n";
```

this help for me

additional info about this bug
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81158